# import a module with a variable

Tags: python-2.7

Hello dear programmers Python language.
I have a question about importing modules in another module with Python 2.7.

I want to know how to import a .py module in the form of a variable.
In fact, I would like to import a module based on the needs of my main module to limit the memory usage of the computer.

For example, suppose I have 25 modules: 1.py, 2.py ... 25.py
Suppose my main module P.y needs, at some point, the modules 2, 7, 15 and 24.py but not the others.
Because, I don't know which modules the main module needs, I currently import all modules with the import function: import 1 2 3 ... 25
Is there a python function to import only the modules 2, 7,15 and 24 with a variable ? (for example: somethink_like_import (variable)
 where variable contains the module name to import.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

```
from importlib import import_module
module = import_module(variable)
```

Example:

```
>>> os = import_module("os")
>>> os.name
'nt'
```

Comment: 'm really sorry but that doesn't work.

For exemple:

a= "Mymodule"

import_module(a) ...

Mymodule.test()

        error : global "mymodule" not defined

where am I a mistake?

Comment: @L.Michel See the example. It should be `mymodule = import_module(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it's working !

variable = "mymodule"

module = __ import__(variable,globals(),locals(),[],-1)

...

module.myfunction() # where function is the name of the function inside mymodule.py